# Wi-Fi problems when downloading

Tags: wireless, intel

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu. Loving it overall. When I first installed I couldn't get wifi to work at all. Through a little searching I found there were others with my model computer that had to disable bluetooth to get wifi to connect which is no big deal as I don't use bluetooth anyway.

After disabling bluetooth I am now able to connect to wifi. I can load webpages without problem. I can watch youtube videos without issue. However, every time I try to download any file my router immediately goes offline. After a minute or so the router will come back up. I will again be fine for regular browsing, but the moment I try to download anything the router will go offline again.

I never had that problem when this laptop was running Windows 10. Just to ensure it wasn't a coincidence I reinstalled Windows and downloading doesn't affect my connection at all. I have put Ubuntu back on my laptop as I prefer it greatly to anything I have ever seen from MS. At present I am having to download any files I want on another Windows computer and transfer them via USB. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Ubuntu version - have tried both 16.04.1 and 16.10 (16.10 currently)
Laptop - Acer Aspire One Cloudbook 14 (A01-431-C8G8)
Router - Arris TG1672G (combo modem router from Time Warner)

```
  description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 3160
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 83
   serial: b4:6d:83:a4:b5:41
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-22-generic firmware=17.352738.0 ip=192.168.0.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:21 memory:91000000-91001fff
```

Comment: I suggest reporting this as a kernel bug.

Comment: I will have to look up how to do that.

Comment: Run in terminal `ubuntu-bug linux` and follow directions.